# How to change UWP app folder name or path?

Tags: uwp, nuget

Renaming UWP app folder or changing its path cause an error which is *'Some assembly references are missing. Building to restore the NuGet cache might resolve this issue.'*

When I create UWP app folder I can see `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package in references node of Solution Explorer but after renaming or moving the folder there is no NuGet package in the node.

I tried building and clearing NuGet cache but nothing changes. 2 options of Package Restore are checked as default. In the case of Windows Forms App with NuGet package, the error is not reproduced. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the **temporary files generated by Visual Studio**. If you open the `obj` folder in the UWP project, you will find several files related to NuGet there. The one that causes your problem is `{AppName}.csproj.nuget.g.props`. You can see that inside of this file there is an absolute path to the `project.assets.json` file:

```
<ProjectAssetsFile Condition=" '$(ProjectAssetsFile)' == '' ">D:\PathToFile\obj\project.assets.json</ProjectAssetsFile>
```

This becomes a problem when you move the solution to another path because this path is no longer valid and is therefore unusable.

The solution is quite simple - close Visual Studio and **delete the `bin` and `obj` folders** from your UWP project.

As a tip - install the **awesome [Clean Solution extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CleanSolution) for Visual Studio** by **Mads Kristensen**. This extension automatically performs a cleanup each time you close Visual Studio - it **collapses all folders** in the solution and also **deletes `bin` and `obj` folders** for each project, so you are starting with a clean slate each time.

Comment: Modificating the path in the file or building after deleting 2 folders solves the problem perfectly. Thanks.